# How to add Ksoap2 Jar file on Netbeans for my android projects

Tags: android, netbeans, netbeans-7

I need to know how to add the ksoap2 jar file into Netbeans for my Android,i was added android soap project But at properties it was not showing existing ksoap2 jar file ,i was deleted that one ,now i'm trying to adding Ksoap2 on Netbeans it was not showing like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use Project properties/Libraries/Add in case of KSOAP2, as it comes in a JAR while NetBeans currrent version 7.4 allows to add NetBeans projects only, not jars.

It is also impossible to add a library by right-clicking Libraries tree in the project as there is no popup menu coming up on right-click.

Correct solution is to open your Android project directory and copy any external libraries you want to import into the `libs` sub-directory. Then close and re-open the project if it was open at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Right-Click on **Libraries** Folder of project-> Select **Add Jar/Folder**-> File Dialog will appear

Then Select appropriate jar or zip file of jar :-
Here there are two options for you

`1) Select jar from external folders of your file system`

`2) Try to make one folder known as libs in your project like we do in eclipse & then select that jar`

Please tell me if you have any problem.

Comment: It is impossible that Libraries won't get right-clicked.Try to visit this click http://monkeybars.rubyforge.org/tutorials/netbeans.html.Read `Adding Libraries` topic.

Comment: Not right clicking on Libraries means just that - you can click, but there will be no popup menu. Not sure about other versions of NetBeans, but in 7.4 that I am using you cannot add JARs to Libraries by right-clicking on Libraries branch under Project tree.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using a maven project, then in the project window, right click on libraries. Select add jar or file, navigate to your jar file and then select it.  It will be available for build/run.

Its best if your jar file is underneath your project on the file system. Then Netbeans will use a relative path to the jar, and that makes the project reusable for other people.

Comment: i tried to add via right clicking but its not clicking on right.

Comment: You should see a node in the tree that is for your project, under that one for source, next one for tests, next one for libraries. Right click that one.

Comment: If you can't find that, right click on the project (in the project window), and select properties. Then select Libraries. It is the same dialog.

Comment: still its not showing in folder, same ksoap2 file i was tried on eclipse it works, in da case of netbeans it was nod displayed on the same folder. i tried on properties->Libraries..etc

Comment: It's clear for me: he is telling you that right-clicking Libraries under NetBeans project tree will not bring up a popup menu. And adding it to the libraries via Project properties is not possible as the Add button brings up a dialogue, that will only select NetBeans project folder, not JARs.

Comment: I've been using netbeans for about eight years now. It's worked that way for most of those years. In fact, I just tried it and it still works that way. If you're not using a Maven project, you can add libraries by right clicking on the libraries node under the project. If that doesn't work for you, then it's not clear to me why that would be so.